# java.sql.sqlexception: at least one parameter to the current statement is uninitialized

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I wrote a java program that is supposed to read a text file line by line, extract certain information and store it to a database table. The program works fine with smaller text files, but when it comes to larger files (12 Mb to be specific), I'm dealing with this error message : java.sql.sqlexception: at least one parameter to the current statement is uninitialized.

This is the method where the error occurs:

```
public void ExtractBoard() throws IOException, SQLException {
    int rows = 0;
    String sqlInser = "INSERT INTO APP.SUBSCRIBERBR (subID, boardno)"+"VALUES (?,?)";
    PreparedStatement  stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sqlInser, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
    String[] AryFiles2 = rf.OpenFile();
    int i,j;
    for (i=0; i<AryFiles2.length; i++) {
        if (AryFiles2[i].contains("ADD VSBR")) {
            String[][] parts = this.LineParts();
            Scanner in = new Scanner(parts[i][0]).useDelimiter("[^0-9]+");
            int intst = in.nextInt();
            String a= String.valueOf(intst);
            stmt.setString(1, a);
            for (j=0; j<parts[1].length; j++) {
                if (parts[i][j].contains("MN")) {
                    Scanner inn = new Scanner(parts[i][j]).useDelimiter("[^0-9]+");
                    int intstr = inn.nextInt();
                    String m= String.valueOf(intstr); 
                    stmt.setString(2,m);
                }
            }
        }
        rows = stmt.executeUpdate();
    }
}
```

Can you please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Look at the last row you inserted.  Then find it in the text file and see what comes after it.

Comment: @DanBracuk The table is still empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The setting of the parameters may be not reachable, check if they are null or not:

```
public void ExtractBoard() throws IOException, SQLException {
    int rows = 0;
    String sqlInser = "INSERT INTO APP.SUBSCRIBERBR (subID, boardno)"+"VALUES (?,?)";
    PreparedStatement  stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sqlInser, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
    String[] AryFiles2 = rf.OpenFile();
    int i,j;
    String p1=null , p2=null;
    for (i=0; i<AryFiles2.length; i++) {
        if (AryFiles2[i].contains("ADD VSBR")) {
            String[][] parts = this.LineParts();
            Scanner in = new Scanner(parts[i][0]).useDelimiter("[^0-9]+");
            int intst = in.nextInt();
            p1 = String.valueOf(intst);
            for (j=0; j<parts[1].length; j++) {
               if (parts[i][j].contains("MN")) {
                   Scanner inn = new Scanner(parts[i][j]).useDelimiter("[^0-9]+");
                   int intstr = inn.nextInt();
                   p2 = String.valueOf(intstr); 

               }
           }
       }
       if(p1 != null && p2 != null){
           stmt.setString(1, p1);
           stmt.setString(2,p2);
           rows += stmt.executeUpdate();
       }
       else{
           \\throw an exception or do what you want
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: You still have to initialize strings 'p1' and 'p2', but this works.Thanks.